# How to figure out what got clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery, how can I figure out what object was clicked?

Is there a way to alert(...) the type of tag? like if it was an `<a href>` or a `<img>` etc?

Comment: Looks like your sample html tags were filtered away. Were they just random examples, or did they have something important in them?

Answer (score 3):

The object that was clicked is passed into the click handler as `this`. You can find out the type of element with `nodeName`. Like this:

```
function handle_click() {
   var clicked_element = this;
   alert(clicked_element.nodeName);
}
$("#mylink").click(handle_click);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Magnar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564110/how-to-figure-out-what-got-clicked/564190#564190) is correct as long as you want to know what type of element *handled* the event (what you attached the event to). If you want to know exactly what element was clicked, including the element's children, you need the [event.target](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.target) property. Using Magnar's example:

```
// show the type of the element that event handler was bound to
function handle_click() {
    var clicked_element = this;
    alert(clicked_element.nodeName);
}

// show the type of the exact element that was clicked, which may be a child
// of the bound element
function handle_child_click(e) {
    var clicked_element = e.target;
    alert(clicked_element.nodeName);
}

// show the type of the element that matches "#myLink"
$("#mylink").click(handle_click);

// show the type of the element that matches "#myLink" or any of its children
$("#mylink").click(handle_child_click);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [jquery docs site](http://docs.jquery.com)!

Specifically, the [Click](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click) event

Answer (score 0):

Could ad an onclick event to alert a attribute

```
<p id='pWoo' onclick='alert(this.id);'>Woo</p>
```

Not specific to jquery.

Comment: In practice, you should probably not embed JavaScript in your HTML... you're better off using an Unobtrusive JavaScript approach (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Might not be what you want but I found this tutorial interesting: http://css-tricks.com/tracking-clicks-building-a-clickmap-with-php-and-jquery/